# fail to create a connection with nessus server

Tags: automation, nessus

I am trying to get a connection with the Nessus server with the bellow command in python but it failed with an error message can you tell me what can be the cause. I have checked my network connection it is fine.

````
requests.post( 'https://164.99.175.30:8834/'+ '/session',data={'username':'admin','password':'micro@123'},verify=False)```


error message 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "nessus.py", line 425, in <module>
    login()
  File "nessus.py", line 111, in login
    res = requests.post(url + '/session',data={'username':username,'password':password},verify=verify)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 119, in post
    return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 530, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 643, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 516, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=8834): Max retries exceeded with url: /session (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f46f2d6d410>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The nessus api is depreciated as of version 7.x, this is the best source I could find.

EDIT: I have found a better source directly from tenable

> What has been removed from Nessus 7:
> There is a restriction in scan API capabilities.
> The ability to manage scans via API and CLI has been removed in v7. All Nessus Pro scanning operations must be done through the user interface.
> So currently the ability of the Nessus API is as follows:

> Removed the ability to run scans or reports and create new objects
> The Read features, where the ability to pull scan data so GET /scan/scan ID now works again and this aids with some of the integration processes.

https://community.tenable.com/s/article/The-differences-between-Nessus-6-and-Nessus-7

This is only for Nessus pro versions